# Customizing and adding woocommerce template data

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, hook

I am having some trouble customizing the woocommerce templates in my wordpress theme. I would like to add additional data as variables in my templates.

I want to show active orders on the dashboard/my-account page. I want to do this by passing in order data variables to the template to be able to call, like how it is done in the `orders.php` template.

I know I can override the `wc-template-functions.php` in my theme and then add the data in the `wc_get_templates` function for the dashboard or my account. However, I don't want to do this.

What I've tried is creating a hook such as:

**functions.php**

```
function wc_fr_add_orders_to_account( $fr_account_orders, $current_page ) {
  global $fr_account_orders;
  $current_page = empty( $current_page ) ? 1 : absint( $current_page );

  $customer_orders = wc_get_orders( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', 
    array( 
      'customer' => get_current_user_id(), 
      'page' => $current_page, 
      'paginate' => true,
      'status' => array( 'wc-pending' )
      ) ) );

  $fr_account_orders = array(
    'current_page' => absint( $current_page ),
    'customer_orders' => $customer_orders,
    'has_orders' => 0 < $customer_orders->total
  );

  return $fr_account_orders;
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_content', 'wc_fr_add_orders_to_account' );
```

**/theme-directory/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/dashboard.php** (also tried in my-account.php)

```
do_action( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard', $fr_account_orders);
var_dump($fr_account_orders);
```

`$fr_account_orders` comes back null. However if I `var_dump` the array in the hook function, it comes back with data. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Eaasy there. If you want to return the variable, that's just not the way to do it. You should use the `apply_filters` like so:

```
function wc_fr_add_orders_to_account() {
    /* your function */

    return $fr_account_orders;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard', 'wc_fr_add_orders_to_account' );
```

and in your template..

```
$my_var = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard', $fr_account_orders );
var_dump( $my_var );
```

now if you want to send some variables do it like so:

```
function wc_fr_add_orders_to_account( $var1, $var2 ) {
    /* your function */

    return $fr_account_orders;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard', 'wc_fr_add_orders_to_account', 10, 3 );
```

and in your template again..

```
$my_var = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_account_dashboard', $fr_account_orders, $var1, $var2 );
var_dump( $my_var );
```

read more about `apply_filters` here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/ one more thing, try not to change templates, but use `add_action` on the `do_action` hooks from template for better compatibility. thanks!

Comment: The pagination did not work correctly when doing this. So instead of creating a filter I just added the code above to my template.

Comment: The pagination is not working because you're using a theme that was coded by someone who didn't care about WordPress or WooCommerce pagination functions. Try any default theme and it'll work as expected ofc.

Answer (score 1):

I tried several ways and couldn't figure out how to keep the pagination correct. This way lists all of the orders on my dashboard.

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => 3, 
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
  'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
  'post_type'   => wc_get_order_types(),
  'post_status' => array ('wc-pending'),
);

$customer_waiting_orders = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $customer_available_orders->have_posts() ) :

  while ( $customer_available_orders->have_posts() ) : $customer_available_orders->the_post();

    //code here    
    wp_reset_postdata();

  endwhile;

endif;
```